# What does “linker input file unused because linking not done” mean?

Tags: makefile

This is weird. The compiler throws this warning though everything works as expected.

This is the makefile that throws the warning:

```
TARGET = $(notdir $(shell pwd))

LIBS = -lm -lev3dev-c
D_BIN = Build-Assets

ifeq ($(OS),Windows_NT)
LIBS := $(LIBS) -lws2_32
D_BIN := $(D_BIN)/mingw
endif

D_H = ../../source/ev3
CFLAGS = $(addprefix -I, $(D_H)) -O2 -std=gnu99 -W -Wall -Wno-comment

ifeq ($(OS),Windows_NT)
CC = gcc
else
CC = arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc
endif

ifeq ($(OS),Windows_NT)
E_BIN = .exe
else
E_BIN =
endif

F_BIN = $(TARGET)$(E_BIN)

OBJECTS = $(addprefix $(D_BIN)/, $(patsubst %.c, %.o, $(wildcard MotorControl/*.c)))

.PHONY: default all clean

default: $(F_BIN)
all: default

$(OBJECTS): $(D_BIN)/%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

.PRECIOUS: $(F_BIN) $(OBJECTS)

$(F_BIN): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(OBJECTS) -c -Wall $(LIBS) -o $@

clean:
    -rm -f $(D_BIN)/*.o
    -rm -f $(F_BIN)
```

I should add that I have no idea what I'm doing... I am just starting out with C and those damn makefiles are very overwhelming.

Answer (score 0):

The [`-c` option](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html#index-c) skips the final link and produces a relocatable object file:

```
$(F_BIN): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(OBJECTS) -c -Wall $(LIBS) -o $@
```

This is why linker input files are not used at this stage.  You should be able to remove the `-c` option, and the command will produce an executable as a result.

Comment: If I remove the option `-c` the compilation fails as it can't find `main()`... I should add that the makefile in the post should compile a sort of 'library', that I use somewhere else (this somewhere else does have main though).

Comment: @A.Dandelion: A shared library, or a static library?

Comment: @Beta I don't know really. Basically I compile this `.c` file, and link the `.o` of this same file in the compilation step of the main `.c` file. I have no idea if that's static/shared or if it's even a library.

Comment: If it doesn't have a `main`, how do you plan to use it? A library contains functions for other programs to use; a program which is runnable by itself needs to have a `main` function so the OS can know its entry point.

Comment: @A.Dandelion: are you saying that this actually works? If so, your compilers must be different from mine. At a guess, I'd say you're creating one big object file, which is like a static library but clunkier.

Comment: @Beta Yes this works. I fixed by removing those lines `$(F_BIN): $(OBJECTS)
 $(CC) $(OBJECTS) -c -Wall $(LIBS) -o $@`. Now only the object file is generated and everything works properly.